# SQL - pull unique name with the lastest date and lowest value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how do i get unique name with the latest date and lowest value.

Name       date        value

brad      1/2/10          1.1

brad       1/2/10         2.3

bob        1/6/10         1.0

brad       2/4/09         13.2

this query does not seem to work

```
  SELECT distinct 
  A.[ViralLoadMemberID]       
  ,B.LastName
  ,B.FirstName
  ,A.[Date]
  ,A.[vaule]  

  FROM [t].[dbo].[tblViralLoad] A
  left join [dbo].[tblEnrollees] B on A.ViralLoadMemberID = B.MemberID
  where 


   A.Date =
   (
   select MAX(Date)
   from dbo.tblViralLoad
   where ViralLoadMemberID = A.ViralLoadMemberID
   and 
   ( Date >= '07/01/2014'
    and Date <= '12/3/2014' ) )
```

Comment: Probably with a combination of grouping by Name and getting Max(Date) and Min (Value)?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried searching SO for a similar question?   `Select name, max(date), min(value) from tablename group by tablename` seems like it would work of did you mean max date and min value independent of name?  if so that's an inline query to get the min/max and a  cross join back to name.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: im using sql sever 2008. i just edited and updated my question @xQbert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use `order by` and fetch only one row.  If you want the lowest value on the latest date, the standard SQL would be:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by desc desc, value asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

For older versions of SQL Server, you would omit the last line and do `select top 1 * . . .`.  For MySQL, the last line would be `limit 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Fun with rank()

```
declare @t as table (name varchar(50),dte date,val decimal(18,10));

insert into @t(name,dte,val) values
('Dave','1/1/2015',1.0),
('Dave','1/3/2015',1.2),
('Dave','1/4/2015',1.5),
('Dave','1/10/2015',1.3),
('Dave','1/15/2015',1.2),
('Steve','1/11/2015',1.6),
('Steve','1/12/2015',1.1),
('Steve','1/15/2015',1.2),
('Bill','1/21/2015',1.9),
('Ted','1/1/2015',1.8),
('Ted','1/10/2015',1.0),
('Ted','1/12/2015',1.7)

-- This will show the lowest prices by each person
select name,dte,val from (select name,dte,val, rank() over (partition by name order by val) as r from @t) as data where r = 1

-- This will be users lowest price and the last day they sublitted a prices regurdless if it is the lowest
select name,max(dte) as [last Date] ,min(val) as [Lowest Value] from @t group by name

-- Who had the lowest price last regurdless if they have raised there price later.
select top(1) name,dte [last lowest quote],val from (select name,dte,val, rank() over (order by val) as r from @t) as data where r = 1 order by dte desc

-- what is the lowest price cueently quoted reguarless who quoted it
select top(1) name,dte [best active quote],val from (select name,dte,val, rank() over (partition by name order by dte desc) as r from @t) as data where r = 1 order by val
```